# How do you change the background color of a ListView's selected item?

Tags: xamarin

Fun fact: `myListView.SelectedItem.GetType() == typeof(object)`. So you can't do it by listening for `ItemTapped` because there is no Background property to set. What you can do is:

```
myListView.ItemTapped += async (object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e) =>
{
    myListView.SelectedItem = null;
};
```

and at least then it won't set the background of the selected item to some random color (in my case bright orange).

But how can you **choose** the background color of the selected item. If you google this question you will see a ton of answers from 2014-2016 that usually involve custom renderers and a ton of code. To me that's not an answer. I'm not going to add a lot of code to get this to work. I'd rather it do nothing at all.

Comment: Fun fact: SelectedItem is the *data* element that has been selected, not the *visual* element, so of course it doesn't have a Background property

Comment: Oh sorry `ItemTappedEventArgs.Item` is a type of object too. But you are right. Setting it to null doesn't seem to break anything though (even after repeated taps). idk. I'm still no closer to an answer.

Comment: @user875234 Add a selected parameter to your model and bind that to your ItemTemplate and set a preferred/selected color via that property, that way when scrolling and the items get recycled and re-populated with data the "color" is reset based upon the new data.

Comment: @SushiHangover I could do that (begrudgingly, lol) but I tried hard coding it to a color and noticed it doesn't change the separator color. So I would end up with this sliver of oranage. Thanks for the answer. I think the right path for me is to do nothing atm.

Answer (score 2):

For Android, you can set in the the resources xml file, as for iOS you will need a CustomRenderer (which as you stated is not an option). There is a feature request for xamarin to add this to Forms. Let's wait.

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/YourColor</item>
   <item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/YourColor</item>
   <item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/YourColor</item>
   <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/YourColor</item>
   <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@color/YourColor</item>
  </style>
<color name="YourColor">#96BCE3</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing in iOS?

Comment: Not without a renderer.

Comment: You know what, that might be good enough. I just noticed iOS is doing a grayish white color which is good enough. I might just set android to use that same color.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to Create CustomRenderer for ListView
Or 
You can also use 
[Sflistview](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/getting-started)

where you get "SelectionBackgroundColor" property